# Cloning git repo to a non root user folder in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Through the next cmd I am trying to clone into the /home/impdev/Impala folder. Yet, docker clones into the root/Impala folder. Is there a way to remedy this?

```
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' impdev && \
    echo 'impdev ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers && \
    su - impdev && \
    git clone https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/impala.git ~/Impala
```

This is important for me as when you clone from an account ownership and group values are assigned to the cloned folder and its sub-folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Dockerfile [`USER`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#user) and [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#workdir) directives to control the current user context.  This might look like

```
USER root
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --no-create-home impdev
WORKDIR /impdev
USER impdev
RUN git clone https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/impala.git
```

Remember that in many ways the Docker environment is different from a typical Linux environment: since an image generally only packages a single application and its immediate dependencies, it's not usually interesting to create multiple users or think about users as having home directories.  You almost never use `su` or `sudo` since a container generally only does one thing and starts up as the user it needs to be to do it.  Both commands are also difficult to use in scripts.  (In your example, if you do `su` to the new user, it completes and returns to the original root-user context before the script moves on to the next command.)